# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'SimpleUploadedFile'

Tags: django-rest-framework, amazon-textract

I am receiving a base64 image via a JSON post action into my Django REST Framework API. Once I have the image, I am using https://aws.amazon.com/textract/ to get the fields and related values from the image. I would like to send the image to textract without saving the image on the Django server nor database.

This is my model:

```
class ocrRequest(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.id, self.created.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

This is my serializer:

```
import boto3

class ocrRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = Base64ImageField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ocrRequest
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        image=validated_data.pop('image')

        #Step I want to avoid:
        #ocr_request = ocrRequest.objects.create(image=image)

        ocr_request = ocrRequest.objects.create()

        img_bytes = image #I believe I need to to a conversion here

        textractmodule = boto3.client('textract')
        response = textractmodule.analyze_document(Document={'Bytes': img_bytes}, FeatureTypes=["FORMS"])
        doc = Document(response)
```

The error that I get is:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 04, 2021 - 06:55:47
Django version 3.2.8, using settings 'myocr.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Method Not Allowed: /api/ocr-request-create/
[04/Nov/2021 06:56:01] "GET /api/ocr-request-create/ HTTP/1.1" 405 5821
[04/Nov/2021 06:56:01] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[04/Nov/2021 06:56:01] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/ajax-form.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[04/Nov/2021 06:56:01] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/default.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[04/Nov/2021 06:56:01] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[04/Nov/2021 06:56:01] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/csrf.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[04/Nov/2021 06:56:01] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/prettify-min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Internal Server Error: /api/ocr-request-create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vant/django/myocr/core/api/views.py", line 92, in ocrRequestCreate
    serializer.save()
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 205, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/home/vant/django/myocr/core/api/serializers.py", line 39, in create
    response = textractmodule.analyze_document(Document={'Bytes': img_bytes}, FeatureTypes=["FORMS"])
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 388, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 680, in _make_api_call
    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 728, in _convert_to_request_dict
    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/validate.py", line 361, in serialize_to_request
    return self._serializer.serialize_to_request(parameters,
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/serialize.py", line 349, in serialize_to_request
    self._serialize(body, parameters, input_shape)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/serialize.py", line 364, in _serialize
    method(serialized, value, shape, key)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/serialize.py", line 384, in _serialize_type_structure
    self._serialize(serialized, member_value, member_shape, member_key)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/serialize.py", line 364, in _serialize
    method(serialized, value, shape, key)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/serialize.py", line 384, in _serialize_type_structure
    self._serialize(serialized, member_value, member_shape, member_key)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/serialize.py", line 364, in _serialize
    method(serialized, value, shape, key)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/serialize.py", line 412, in _serialize_type_blob
    serialized[key] = self._get_base64(value)
  File "/home/vant/virtualenvs/myocr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/serialize.py", line 170, in _get_base64
    return base64.b64encode(value).strip().decode(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'SimpleUploadedFile'
[04/Nov/2021 06:56:12] "POST /api/ocr-request-create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 183540
```

So I need to convert my "SimpleUploadedFile" (which is in base64 format) to a bytes-like object without waiting for a physical file to be produced that I can later read.

Would anyone know how to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the full error? I can see which row it occurred on now.

Comment: if img is your base64 string you can simply do `base64.decodebytes(img)`